# C++ Template<Operator>

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I'm currently building a BigInt class and, when overloading the operators &, | and ^, which will all have similar function syntax, I wondered if it would be possible to template the operators themselves as such:

```
template<operator K> 
BigInt operator K( const BigInt& a, const BigInt& b )
{
 BigInt Result = 0;
 uint64_t Max = max(a.GetSize() , b.GetSize()) /* max(a,b) is defined outside */
 for (uint64_t n=0; n < Max; n++)
 {
  Result[n] = a[n] K b[N];
 }
 return Result;
}
```

Where A[n] returns a bool with the nth digit of A (binary), and apply this to the operators &, | and ^, this way I wouldn't write 3 operator overloads that are identical for the exception of 2 letters.

I know this syntax doesn't work, but I'm asking if there is any way to do what you might expect this syntax to do: substitute K by &, | or ^ and only those when you write (a & b) in the code.

If it helps here is my definition of the class:

```
class BigInt
{
private:
    vector<bool> num;

public:
    /* Constructors */
    BigInt();
    template<class T> BigInt(T);

    /* Class Methods */
    void RLZ(); /* Remove Leading Zeroes */
    uint64_t GetSize() const;
    void print();

    /* Operator Overloads */
    std::vector<bool>::reference operator[] (uint64_t);
    bool operator[] (uint64_t) const;
    BigInt& operator=(const BigInt&);
};
```

Comment: I don't think you can use an operator as a template parameter. I'll wait for somebody to prove me wrong.

Comment: @RSahu: [std::plus and friends](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional#Operator_function_objects) :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One idea would be to define a helper function templated on the operator *function* (since you can't template on the operator itself), and then instantiate your template in the definitions of the appropriate BigInt operators.  For example:

```
template <class OperatorFn> 
BigInt bitwiseOperator(const BigInt& a, const BigInt& b) const
{
    BigInt Result = 0;
    uint64_t Max = max(a.GetSize(), b.GetSize());
    for (uint64_t n=0; n < Max; n++)
    {
        Result[n] = OperatorFn{}(a[n], b[N]);
    }
    return Result;
}
BigInt operator&(const BigInt& a, const BigInt& b) const { return bitwiseOperator<std::bit_and<bool>>(a, b); }
BigInt operator|(const BigInt& a, const BigInt& b) const { return bitwiseOperator<std::bit_or<bool>>(a, b); }
BigInt operator^(const BigInt& a, const BigInt& b) const { return bitwiseOperator<std::bit_xor<bool>>(a, b); }
```

Comment: When I try to run it, g++ gives me the error "no matching function to call 'std::bit_and<bool>::bit_and(bool, bool) '", although the code does make sense to me, it seems like a perfect solution outside of this error. I also had to drop the const modifiers because it told me "non-member function 'BigInt bitwiseOperator(const BigInt&, const BigInt&) cannot have cv-qualifier '" but without the const it works fine (The function const, not the argument const).

Comment: @FilipeRodrigues Make sure you `#include <functional>`, and you may need to change `OperatorFn(a[n], b[N]);` to `OperatorFn{}(a[n], b[N]);` since `bit_and` and the rest are actually function objects, not functions.

Comment: The #include <function> wasn't necessary, it seems that the only problem was the missing {}, it works with no errors now, I assume the std::bit_and are included either in vector or iostream, which are the only includes I currently have, either that or they don't need an include.

Answer (score 5):

I would write this:

```
template<class F>
BigInt& bitwiseReplace( F&& f, BigInt& lhs, BigInt const& rhs ) {
  auto max = (std::max)(lhs.GetSize(), rhs.GetSize());
  for (uint64_t i=0; i < max; ++i)
    lhs[i] = f( lhs[i], rhs[i] );
  return lhs;
}
```

note that I take `lhs` by reference and modify it.  This is on purpose.  This corresponds to `&=` and `|=`.

```
template<class F>
BigInt bitwiseCreate( F&& f, BigInt lhs, BigInt const& rhs ) {
  bitwiseReplace( std::forward<F>(f), lhs, rhs );
  return lhs;
}
```

this corresponds to `+` or `|`.

In your class:

```
BigInt& operator=(const BigInt&)=default;
BigInt& operator=(BigInt&&)=default;
BigInt(const BigInt&)=default;
BigInt(BigInt&&)=default;
```

have default move/copy assign/construct, as they do the right thing here.

Now you just have to write one line:

```
BigInt& operator&=( BigInt const& rhs ) { return bitwiseReplace( std::bit_and<bool>{}, *this, rhs ); }
BigInt& operator|=( BigInt const& rhs ) { return bitwiseReplace( std::bit_or<bool>{}, *this, rhs ); }

friend BigInt operator&( BigInt lhs, BigInt const& rhs ) { return bitwiseCreate( std::bit_and<bool>{}, std::move(lhs), rhs ); }
friend BigInt operator|( BigInt lhs, BigInt const& rhs ) { return bitwiseCreate( std::bit_or<bool>{}, std::move(lhs), rhs ); }
```

this requires a small amount of glue code.

The left hand side being taken by value means that

```
auto r = a | b | c;
```

is efficient -- the result of `a | b` is moved (well actually elided) into `(a|b) | c` with no copies performed.

Another advantage of this is that you can replace your `std::vector<bool>` with a `std::vector<uint32_t>`.  Just write `wordwiseReplace` and `wordwiseCreate` that takes a function and operates on each `uint32_t` in a very similar way.

You can with a bit of additional work even implement `+` and `-` this way.  The function object can carry the carry information.  You do have to check if there is overflow/underflow at the end and adjust for it.

`*` and `/` will require more work.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I feel like this one is slightly more complex and unnecessary than the other, as this is just a small library for personal use for now, if I ever make a bigger library I'll consider these practices, and the reason I have an std::vector<bool> is that it acts like an std::bitset, this means that it occupies less memory than uint32_t, which is 32 bits vs 1 bit.

Comment: @FilipeRodrigues I mean, your big int should be constructed out of 32 bit chunks not 1 bit chunks.  So a 128 bit value instead of having `num.size()==128` has `num.size()==4`.  This permits *much* faster `+` and `-` and the like, as you can use machine `+` and `-` instead of having to manually carry each bit around.

Comment: Ah, yes that does make sense, I have in the past done one similar to the one you're saying with uint64_t but by piecing together uint64_t types in a dynamic array, instead of a vector, but with this library I wanted to try to create a bit per bit library mostly to get more experience with bit twiddling and just binary operations in general.